# Create and view by has_many :through association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, has-many-through

I am using rails4 and also new to ROR.

I am using devise to create User. There is "workspace" model which is related to user though "user_workspace" model.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   has_many :user_workspaces
   has_many :workspaces, through: :user_workspaces
end
```

**workspace.rb**

```
 class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :user_workspaces
    has_many :user_workspaces
 end
```

**user_workspace.rb**

```
class UserWorkspace < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :workspace
end
```

I want to create a workspace and show it in the index page

**workspace_controller**

```
def create
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
  @user_worspace = @user.user_workspaces.build(params[:user_worspace])
  @workspace = @user_worspace.build_workspace(params[:workspace].permit(:name))
 if @workspace.save
 flash[:notice] = "workspace created"
     redirect_to workspaces_path
 else
    flash[:error] = "Name cant be blank"
    redirect_to workspaces_path
 end
end

 def index
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
  @user_worspace = @user.user_workspaces.build(params[:user_worspace])
  @workspace = @user_worspace.build_workspace

  @users = current_user.user_workspaces.collect(&:workspace_id)
  @workspaces =@users.workspaces.all
 end
```

I have given new in my index as I am using modal view to create new workspace form the index page.

**index.html.erb**

```
 <div class = "container">
<% if @users.present? %>
    <% @workspaces.each do |workspace| %>
      <div class= "workspace-list"> 
      <strong><%= link_to workspace.name, workspaces_show_path(workspace.id) %></strong>       </div>
   <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

I would like to know the exact way of creating and displaying the things using has_many :throught association.

Comment: besides some typos, your strukture seems ok, is there something specific that isn't working?

Comment: What is the issue you're having? What have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to create a workspace which has a name attribute and display the name in the view page which I am unable to do with the above code. What should I do to make the name of the workspace visible in the view page.